# How would you make "receive only" wild card emails on your domain?

Tags: php, email

I have this scenario - new users will get their unique email address on my domain.
The inbox will be just for receiving and reading emails ( by users) and programmatic
access to i (by me).

I guess i would have to have a hosting account with wild card email allowed.

Is there something simple i'm missing? If not, how should i do it?

PS. I've seen services like Google Apps, Zoho Mail etc, but i'd like to stick to self
hosted way .

**EDIT:** If that would be a requirement i could use a small VPS for that purpose.

Comment: does it *have* to be email or could you not implement a messaging system, such as forum PM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Cpanel has "catch all" and "pipe to program" option. Thats a solution for now. 
Source:
http://stuporglue.org/add-an-email-address-that-forwards-to-a-script/